# Divide a cubed quadratic polynomial by $x^2+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider a quadratic polynomial $f(x)=x^2+\cdots $  with $f(1)=0$.

Divide $\{f(x)\}^3$ by $x^2+1$, and let the quotient $Q(x)$ be $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.

The question
is to find $|13a+7b+3c+d|$.

The answer is $21$(I used a computer program), but I need to know a simpler way to find it.

There is no information about the remainder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to know a simpler way to do it so where is your way? It would be good to provide your workings.

Comment: The quotient is as given : is there nothing given about the remainder? (Or is the remainder zero?)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the remainder doesn't matter, so Greg Martin's answer is fine.  Here's a cleaner way to get the result.  Let $P(x) = (f(x))^3$.  We have

$$P(x) = Q(x)(x^2+1) + ex+f$$

$$P'(x) = Q(x)(2x) + Q'(x)(x^2+1) + e$$

$$P''(x) = Q(x)(2) + 2Q'(x)(2x)+Q''(x)(x^2+1)$$

Since $x=1$ is a root of $f(x)$ it is a triple root of $P(x)$ and hence a root of $P''(x)$.  So we have

$$P''(1) = Q(1)(2)+2Q'(1)(2)+Q''(1)(2) = 0.$$

That is

$$2(1+a+b+c+d)+4(4+3a+2b+c) +2(12+6a+2b)=0$$

$$21+13a+7b+3c+d = 0.$$

So your answer is $21.$

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer is incomplete, and anyway [B. Goddard's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3708532/16078) is better!*

Let $P(x) = f(x)^3 = Q(x)(x^2+1) = (x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)(x^2+1)$. Since $f(1)=0$, we know that $P(x) = f(x)^3$ has a triple zero at $x=1$, so that $P(1)=P'(1)=P''(1)=0$. This is a set of three linear equations in the four variables $a,b,c,d$, and the solution is
$$
b = -3a-6, \quad c=3a+8, \quad d=-a-3.
$$
Therefore $13+7+3+ = 13+7(-3a-6)+3(3a+8)+(-a-3) = -21$.

Comment: I really appreciated!!

Comment: What if the remainder is not zero? It seems that the answer is still $21$ even if the remainder is not zero.

Comment: @Greg Martin You have assumed that $x^2+1$ perfectly divides $(f(x))^3$. But that isn't mentioned in the question.